# docx and excel downloaded files giving error

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have created new docx, xlsx and xls files from my windows 10 > office 2007. In which I have written only one word that is "testing123". I am using following code to download the files.

```
$file = storage_path("app/".$directory_name."/".$filename);
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type( $file ),
);
return response()->download($file, $filename ,$headers);
```

I tried to use following content types as well statically.

```
'application/octet-stream', // txt etc
    'application/msword', // doc
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', //docx
    'application/vnd.ms-excel', // xls
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', // xlsx
    'application/pdf', // pdf
```

But I am getting following error.

> Excel can not open the file testing.xlsx because the file format or
>   file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been
>   corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

What could be the solution in this case? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to add this:
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\"");

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error in Excel - not in your browser or in the application, so the download is probably working fine, the issue is with the content of the file and how it is created. Your next step is to verify this by checking the content file downloaded against that which is stored on the server.

Comment: I am not creating it dynamically using any programming language. It is static file. I am creating it using Microsoft office 2007. I have written only one word in this file.

Comment: Doesn't matter. You still need to check the file has not been truncated or transformed in some way.